# Got some problems after using "ui boxer"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8jS6d/

I have modified a little bit of it, but I want to know further about this plugin.
(I knew some jQuery usages.)

1. I found out the function `widget` has a lot of methods, can you tell me which one is the "reserve words"? How about `ui-boxer` and `ui-boxer-disabled` ?
2. Is it possible to add a name (the text inside the div) on every div after creating? I've tried many times, but it did not work. (I don't want all `div`s to have the same name). For example: create first `div` which has `innerHTML` set to 'div-1', second div with `innerHTML` set to 'div-2' and etc. (see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw1a0txhbz8y1ps/Edit%20fiddle%20-%20JSFiddle%202013-12-19%2016-40-31.png) example)

Is it here where I should modify?

```
$('#test').boxer({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var offset = ui.box.offset();
    ui.box.css({ border: '1px solid white', background: '#EEEEEE' });
    // here?
  }
});
```

Hope you can help me, I got this plugin without any documentation, so I am confused.
(I forgot who is the author too)

Comment: What do you mean by  `create first div which html is 'div-1'` - do you mean the tag name? It would be invalid HTML then

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression,
I mean this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw1a0txhbz8y1ps/Edit%20fiddle%20-%20JSFiddle%202013-12-19%2016-40-31.png

Comment: OMG, thank you @Ivaylo Slavov
I'm still trying...!

Comment: No problem. The power of StackOverflow is the capability to improve the posts and emphasize on the important information. One day you can also edit yours and other's posts to make them clearer and prettier. As for the issue, I wish I could help you but I am not familiar with that plugin. I would try something like `$("#test").boxer({ content: "div-1", stop: ....`, but this is merely a guess.

Comment: OK!!
Thanks for your tips, I am giving a try.

Comment: Is it right to write code in "stop" ?

Comment: maybe, it could be the event handler that is invoked when mouse operations is done. You could actually add the inner html of the div there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. I do not understand what you are asking. Do you mean "reserved words"? The ones you mention are simply class names applied to the element you connect `boxer` to. What is your concern with those names?

Q2. Your JSFiddle seems to be very close to what you wanted. The example below does what you seem to be asking, by using a classname for the added elements and counting those elements to get the next number.

```
  // Using the boxer plugin
  $('#test').boxer({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      //var offset = ui.box.offset();
      ui.box.css({ border: '1px solid white', background: '#EEEEEE' });
      ui.box.addClass("newdiv");
      ui.box.append("div-" + $('.newdiv').length);
    }
  });
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/8jS6d/1/

If this is not what you wanted, please clarify your problem.